# WARNING: Converting ill-formed UTF-16. Your Protocol Buffer will not round trip correctly! -Protocol Buffers

Tags: character-encoding, protocol-buffers, utf-16

I am installing the Java Protocolbuffer compiler and a warning was prompting during the Build Process of installation of Maven

com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream writeStringNoTag
WARNING: Converting ill-formed UTF-16. Your Protocol Buffer will not round trip correctly!

INFO: Processed 11 million characters

It's been running for 8hrs now. However, there is no error prompted.
I am just not sure that this is normal when installing Java Protocol Buffer compiler.

I am on the 'mvn install' on the installation procedure of Protocol Buffer.

Please help!!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per advice, just wait for it to finish and safely ignore the WARNING as long as there are no errors. As it is searching and iterating all possible 3-byte UTF-8 symbols.

I waited for the installation to finish or prompt any errors (none appeared). The installation is done after 30hrs of running. It processed for over 16 million characters.

I am still waiting for an answer if memory and disk space affects the installation of Protocol Buffer. However, I think this may help someone in the future if they come accross the same issue. I'll post or comment the answer to my question once posted.

Thanks!